# How can I do? I accidentally delete google and alexa verification meta code

Tags: google, google-search-console, alexa, site-verification

I accidentally delete Google and Alexa verification `<meta>` code from `<head>` and all have gone.

I went to both Google Webmaster tools and Alexa but I cannot find where I can get verification meta code again.

Anyone know where I can get it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you still have the ID's you can find a list of the major [verification sites](http://www.bybe.net/blog/list-of-webmaster-verification-and-verify-sites.html) on a blog post I wrote donkeys ago, here's a direct paste of all the major Verification Sites Meta's I've discovered to date should you want to verify your site with even more than just [Alexa](http://www.alexa.com) and [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).

1. Google Webmaster Tools - `<meta name="google-site-verification" content=" " />`
2. Google Apps - `<meta name="google-site-verification" content=" " />`
3. Microsoft Bing Webmaster Tools - `<meta name="msvalidate.01" content=" " />`
4. Alexa - `<meta name="alexaVerifyID" content=" " />`
5. Norton Safeweb - `<meta name="norton-safeweb-site-verification" content=" " />`
6. Mywot - `<meta name="wot-verification" content=" " />`
7. Yandex Webmaster Tools - `<meta name="yandex-verification" content=" " />`
8. Pinterest - `<meta name="p:domain_verify" content=" " />`

I personally use Google Webmaster Tools, Microsoft Webmaster Tools, Alexa and even Norton Safeweb and Mywot as these are good for local rankings with reviews and stuff.

Here's some instructions how you can verify your sites again with Google and Alexa, If you have any questions please comment.

Google Webmaster Tools

1. Go to http://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home and Login
2. Click Your Domain
3. Click HTML Method if listed or Verify using a different method.
4. Copy the ID and enter it into the content=" " />
5. Copy it into the `<head> </head>` within your HTML

Alexa

1. Go to http://www.alexa.com
2. Sign in to your account or make an account
3. Once logged in search for your site and click edit listing then follow on screen information.

Comment: You want codes again because Google Webmaster Tools periodically checks for them.

Comment: Ya your right, dunno what I was thinking.. Just checked my own site and its because I have TXT records on the domain, updated answer and remitted incorrect information... Thanks Fiasco for putting me right :P

Comment: I know because Webmaster Tools yelled at me about it. Oops! <grin>

Answer (score 0):

For Google go to [verification details in webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home).  From there choose "Verification details" and then "Verify using a different method".  From that screen you can choose meta tag method to get your details back.

I have not personally claimed my site in Alexa, but their site for doing so is here: http://www.alexa.com/siteowners/claim